# How to generate double pairs from array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array like this: `var array = [111, 222, 000, 111, 111, 000, 1111]`
So far so good.
**How to assign all values of the array to max. 2-slot groups that have the same value and get the index of** *(+ later remove all groups that are smaller than 2 elements)* ? 
Just like this:

```
var result = {["111" : "0, 3"], ["222" : "1"], ["000" : "2, 5"], ["111" : "4, 6"]}
```

(
    `var end_result = {["111" : "0, 3"], ["000" : "2, 5"], ["111" : "4, 6"]}` )

> :-: "111" is the value
>   
>    :-: "0, 3" are the first 2 indexes of the array

Comment: Have you made a start? You can't expect so community to do your homework

Comment: shoul the result are arrays insinde of the array or objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object as hash table for single slots.

```js
var array = [111, 222, 000, 111, 111, 000, 111],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (hash[a]) {
            hash[a][1] += ', ' + i;
            hash[a] = 0;
            return r;
        }
        hash[a] = [a, i];
        return r.concat([hash[a]]);
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```